# Selenium switch to iframe not working in ruby

Tags: ruby, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm unable to find an element after switching to an iframe. I believe `driver.switch_to.frame("homeFrame")` is failing. I can locate other elements on the page that are not in the iframe, but I can't get anything inside the iframe.

Here is my mock ruby:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

begin
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
    driver.navigate.to "file:///Users/$USER_NAME/Desktop/iframe/index.html"
    driver.switch_to.frame("homeFrame")
    link = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[5]/a")
    link.click
end
```

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/spencerdcarlson/f29b9833608f6f2f2bbf) with all the example code and the HTML I am working with.

1. a-main.rb - mock example ruby script
2. b-index.html - HTML that contains the iframe element
3. c-homeFrame-iframe.html - HTML inside the iframe

Here is the link to the gist https://gist.github.com/spencerdcarlson/f29b9833608f6f2f2bbf

Comment: Just a fast observation, you may need to find this iframe element first before switching to it. For example: iframeLocation = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("//iframe[@*******]"), then driver.switch_to_frame(iframeLocation). Hope this helps. I am sorry I am using python in my example.

Comment: @YuZhang Thanks for your help, but the ruby `Selenium::WebDriver::Driver#switch_to` doesn't support accepting a `Selenium::WebDriver::Element` as an argument, nor does it support passing in a `Selenium::WebDriver::Element#FINDERS` key value pair (:id "homeFrame") It only accepts the id attribute of the iframe element. I've been searching the documentation for other options. Here is the [switch_to](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Driver.html#switch_to-instance_method)

Comment: It looks like src attribute of the iframe was set by javascript and I needed to click somewhere on the the page to trigger the js. I am now able to locate elements inside the iframe by id, but xpath isn't working. I need to use xpath in this case because the element I need doesn't have an id attribute

Comment: I have no idea why, but using `link = driver.find_elements(:css, "#app-dashbrd-page > div > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a")` instead of `:xpath` worked. I tried to recreate the issue using two simple html files but xpath worked fine. I think the issue is specific to the websites I'm working with